# forward declaration in two headers and two cpp files

Tags: c++, cyclic-reference, file-inclusion

I have four C++ files, two headers and two cpp. The headers are properly guarded and in the first I use a forward declaration like this:

```
//A.h
class B;

class A {
public:
    A();
    void doSomething(B* b);
};
```

and some implementation:

```
void A::doSomething(B* b){
    b->add();
}
```

the other header is as follows:

```
#include "A.h"
class B {
public:
    B();
    void add();
};
```

and

```
void B::add(){
    cout << "B is adding" << endl;
}
```

I get the "member access into incomplete type B" error and I'm stuck in there. I need to use a  of Bs into A and each B must have a pointer to its "owner", an instance of A. What can I do to solve this situation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add `#include "B.h"` in A.cpp.

Comment: @RSahu .. you are utterly correct. I just needed some clarification form myself. Thnks

Answer (score 0):

The `B.cpp` file, despite named similarly, does not implicitly include `B.h`. You have to include the `B.h` from both implementations. Also, if you want to include **both** `A.h` **and** `B.h`, create the **include guards**

Comment: I've guarded both headers and certainly included B.h in B.cpp

Answer (score 0):

solved the issue by using forward declarations in both A and B class definitions (headers) and including A.h in B.cpp and also B.h in A.cpp. Here's the code:

```
//A.h

#ifndef A_H_
#define A_H_

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class B;

class A{
public:
    A();
    virtual ~A();

private:
    B* pToB;

public:
    void doSomething(B* b);
    void SetB(B* b);
};

#endif
```

The cpp for A class, note the inclusion of B.h (this I wouldn't normally do)

```
// A.cpp

#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

A::A():pToB(){
    cout << "A constructor" << endl;
}

A::~A(){}

void A::SetB(B* b){
    this->pToB = b;
    cout << "setting B" << endl;
}

void A::doSomething(B* b){
cout << "A is gonna call B's method add: ";
    b->add();
}
```

now the B class:

```
// B.h

#ifndef B_H_
#define B_H_

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A;

class B{
public:
    B();
    virtual ~B();

private:
    A* pToA;

public:
    void add();
    void SetA(A* a);
};

#endif
```

implementation for B

```
// B.cpp

#include "B.h"
#include "A.h"

B::B():pToA(){
    cout << "B constructor” << endl;
}

B::~B(){}

void B::SetA(A* a){
    this->pToA = a;
    cout << "setting A" << endl;
}

void B::add(){
    cout << "B is adding" << endl;
}
```

the cpp including main function (both headers included, did not include )

```
#include "A.h"
#include "A.h"

int main() {
    A* newA = new A;
    B* newB = new B;
    newA->SetB(newB);
    newB->SetA(newA);
    newA->doSomething(newB);
    return 0;
}
```

the output for this programme is like this:

```
A constructor
B constructor
setting B
setting A
A is gonna call B's method add: B is adding
```

thanks to [Sandeep Datta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/39648/sandeep-datta) whose [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/625801/1437544) helped me to solve this issue

Answer (score -1):

You need to have the definition for class B before you can use the `doSomething(B* b)` method, so I think instead of:

```
class B;

class A {
public:
    A();
    void doSomething(B* b);
};
```

you would need to do something like:

```
class B;

class A {
public:
    A();
};

void A::doSomething(B* b);
```

declaring it after so the compiler has the information it needs about class B (memory allocation, etc).

Comment: unfortunately this produces the following error: "out-of-line declaration of 'doSomething' does not match any declaration in 'A'"

Comment: You need to have the definition of `B` before you can _use_ `B` (whether by declaring a variable of type `B`, or by using a member of `B`).  You only need a declaration for `B` to declare a _pointer or reference_ to `B`.  See [this example](http://ideone.com/2O5qfU).  (This is because the members of `B` need to be known to compute the size of `B` or allow them to be used, but the size of a pointer generally isn't modified by the members (and references officially aren't actual entities so much as new names for pre-existing entities, but are typically implemented via pointers).)